# How to to a $http request from a service when an angular js app starts?

Tags: angularjs

I have a session service and I want to check if an auth token is valid.
From the session service I will do a $http request.

How can I do a $http request in angular js before the app starts?
Basically, before any route becomes available?

If there is a way to do this, the Session service would have valid, server data regarding the token.

Any ideas?q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bes way is to do it in a run block of module

```
  angular.module('yourApp').run(['$rootScope', '$http', function ($rootScope, $http) {
  // $http request here
 }]);
```

And as @methews Suggested, have a look on these Documentation

[Angular Docs On this](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module#module-loading-dependencies)